# Test class to cover PageReference

Tags: apex

Please let me know how to cover below line in apex test class:

```
 PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+acc.ID);
 pageRef.setRedirect(true);
 return pageRef;
```

Below is the test code I wrote:

```
Test.setCurrentPageReference(new PageReference('/'+acc.Id));
System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('id', acc.id);
```

Code is still not covered.
Please see below screen shot.

Here is test class ocde.

```
 PageReference pageRef1 = Page.AccountCustomerExtn5;//PageName
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef1);
pageRef1.getParameters().put('id',cust1.id);//Id
 ApexPages.StandardController stdCtr = new ApexPages.StandardController(cust1);
AccountCustomerExtn5 ctr1 = new AccountCustomerExtn5(stdCtr);
ctr1.customSave();
```

[image]

Comment: your catch block is executing, that means you got an error at `upsert attachmentObj` line. Prepare appropriate data for your test class.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you need to do to cover those lines. They are statements that will execute based on the surrounding code requirements.

You do however need to use asserts and the returned page reference provides the data needed to assert the returned value is as expected.

**Update**

Based on your edit

you are having an error inserting the attachment, catching the error, and displaying the message. In your test you can debug / properly assert the page messages to see why the error is happening and fix it.

In your test you can temporarily do this to see the message:

```
system.assertEquals(null,ApexPages.getMessages()[0].getDetail());
```

remove it when done or it will throw an error if no messages exist

Comment: Hi Himanshu, code still not covered.

Comment: @sohel - No idea who Himanshu is, but if it is not covered you need to provide more information including the surrounding code, especially logical checks.

Comment: @sohel - See edit. You need to find out why the error is being thrown. BTW is this what you meant by Himanshu :) http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=himanshu

Comment: @eric..you are right its based on the conditions,but if you want to pass page reference method so we need to pass the id and page name in test class to cover that part.yeah my name meaning is same that defined in urbandictionary:)

Comment: @Himanshujasuja - Getting the right page reference is different that "covering the lines" and is secondary to your issue. Your first issue as posed in your question is how to cover the lines.....

Answer (score 0):

Set the pagename in your test class and then run.

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.yourPageName;//PageName
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
pageRef.getParameters().put('id',acc.id);//Id
```